# Laravel: what does schedule:finish do?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I discovered for an incident that Laravel 6 `schedule:run` has a brother, called `schedule:finish`

But using `artisan list` it's not documented.

What does this console command do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This hidden command added on Laravel 5.4 to handle the after callbacks of a given command.

Check *Taylor Otwell*'s explanations on [this PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/16806):

> This PR adds improvements to the scheduler. Previously, when
>   `->runInBackground()` was used "after" hooks were not run, meaning
>   output was not e-mailed to the developer (when using `emailOutputTo`.)
>
> This change provides a new, hidden `schedule:finish` command that is
>   used to fire the after callbacks for a given command by its mutex
>   name. This command will not show in the Artisan console command list
>   since it uses the hidden command feature which is new in Symfony 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

`schedule:finish` is used to setup actions for a process after its finishes execution,
if you have two or three level of processes that you want them to be executed one after another and depending on each other you use the `schedule:finish` command